# JavaScript swap function with 3 items - reversable

Tags: javascript

I have three colours in an array. Initally I was asked to create a function that would simply take the first one and append it to the end or do the reverse, so I created this function:

```
// Get our colours
var colours = scope.colours;

// Create our function
scope.swap = function (opposite) {

    // If we want to go in the opposite direction
    if (opposite) {

        // Shift the array in reverse
        colours.unshift(colours.pop());

    // Else
    } else {

        // Shift the array
        colours.push(colours.shift());
    }
};
```

this worked fine.
Now my client has asked me for something more complicated and I am just want to see if there is an easy way to do this.

They have given me a table a bit like this:

---

### | C1 | C2 | C3 |

### | C2 | C1 | C3 |

### | C1 | C3 | C2 |

### | C2 | C3 | C1 |

So basically,

- **C3** can only be in position 2 and 3
- **C2 and C1** can be in any position

Before I start messing around, does anyone know of a simple way of doing this?

### Possible solution

So, after I wrote this, I decided to have a go anyway.
I came up with this:

```
// Get our colours
var colours = scope.colours;

// Create our variables
counter = 2;

// Create our function
scope.swap = function (opposite) {

    switch (counter) {
        case 3:

            // Get our colours
            var colour2 = colours.shift();
            var colour3 = colours.shift();

            // Rearange them
            colours.splice(1, 0, colour2);
            colours.splice(2, 0, colour3);

            // Exit the switch
            break;

        case 1:

            // Get our colours
            var colour2 = colours.shift();
            var colour1 = colours.shift();

            // Rearange them
            colours.splice(0, 0, colour1);
            colours.splice(2, 0, colour2);

            // Exit the switch
            break;
        case 0:

            // Get our colours
            var colour1 = colours.shift();
            var colour3 = colours.shift();

            // Rearange them
            colours.splice(1, 0, colour3);
            colours.splice(2, 0, colour1);

            // Exit the switch
            break;
        default:

            // Remove and store our first array value
            var colour1 = colours.shift();

            // Add the colour into the array in the second position
            colours.splice(1, 0, colour1);

            // Exit the switch
            break;
    }

    // Decrease
    counter--;

    // If our counter is less than 0
    if (counter < 0) {

        // Reset the counter
        counter = 3;
    }
};
```

Because there will never be more than 3 colours I just built in a switch statement and used **shift()** to re-arrange my array.
Now this woks great, but what happens if I want to go in the other direction? i.e. instead of decreasing the counter, I want to be able to increase it too (and reset to 0 when greater than 3).

Comment: Of doing what? You've given specifics of what a function can and cannot do but not its purpose.

Comment: If it's four permutations just hardcode them. No need to find some complex logic that is likely to change again when your customer will change idea.

Comment: `client` ... that's not how to spell teacher

Comment: lol @JaromandaX it actually is a client :)

Comment: @r3plica I would recommend that you don't embed answers (or possible answers in your question. Post an answer instead.

Comment: @r3plica I would also recommend not to change requirements after people have already worked on it, like your client do :) Post a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it's four permutations just hardcode them. No need to elaborate some complex logic that is likely to change again when your customer will change idea.

```
var C1 = '#ff0000',
    C2 = '#00ff00',
    C3 = '#0000ff',
    permutations = [
        [C1, C2, C3],
        [C2, C1, C3],
        [C1, C3, C2],
        [C2, C3, C1]
    ],
    currentPermutationIndex = 0;

function swap() {
    currentPermutationIndex = (currentPermutationIndex + 1) % 4;
}

function backSwap() {
    // the following doesn't work, see edit
    currentPermutationIndex = (currentPermutationIndex - 1) % 4;
}
```

Usage example: http://jsfiddle.net/acasaccia/qy56x8o0/

[EDIT]: Unfortunately the lack of a proper `mod` operator to treat negative numbers in Javascript makes the solution for `backSwap` less neat: we need to implement a `mod` polyfill until they implement [this](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3Amodulo_operator) proposal, and use it instead of `%`:

```
Number.prototype.mod = function(n) {
    return (((this)%n)+n)%n;
}
```

```
function swap() {
    currentPermutationIndex = (currentPermutationIndex + 1).mod(4);
}

function backSwap() {
    currentPermutationIndex = (currentPermutationIndex - 1).mod(4);
}
```

Comment: Although this is a pretty good solution, because AngularJS uses 2 way binding and I would like to keep that, I cant use this method because it only gives me an index of the correct order. To get the original array to match that can't be done

Comment: So basically, you can't accept this answer because it's not working with a framework you didn't even mention in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function. I think this might help you. This will work with any combination of your client:

**Function definition**

```
function calculatePosition(colorArr, element, fixedPositionArr) {
    var result = [], usedElement = [];
    var permutationArr = (function recursive() {
        for (var i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i++) {
            var ch = colorArr.splice(i, 1)[0];
            usedElement.push(ch);
            if (colorArr.length == 0) {
                result.push(usedElement.slice());
            }
            recursive();
            colorArr.splice(i, 0, ch);
            usedElement.pop();
        }
        return result;
    })();


    return permutationArr.filter(function(arr){
        var elementPos = parseInt(arr.indexOf(element));
        if(fixedPositionArr.indexOf(elementPos) > -1) return true;

    })
}
```

**Function call three elements**

```
var color = new Array('c1', 'c2', 'c3');
var fixedPositionArr = [1, 2];

var res = calculatePosition(color, 'c3', fixedPositionArr)
console.log(res);
```

**Function call four elements**

```
var color = new Array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');
var fixedPositionArr = [2, 3];

var res = calculatePosition(color, 'c4', fixedPositionArr)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: is it not a bit complex for a simple array of four values?

Comment: I was just about to say that, it looks really complicated. I have written something, about to update my question

Comment: As I tried to any make it work with any number of array element, it took time and became big. But I think it's giving you the output you wanted. :)